# Change individual vertex attributes in python igraph

Tags: python, list, igraph

For a given graph `g` I cannot change an individual vertex attribute (in this case `'color'`):

```
from igraph import Graph

# create triangle graph
g = Graph.Full(3)

cl_blue = (0,0,.5)
cl_red = (.5,0,0)

g.vs['color'] = 3*[cl_blue]
g.vs['color'][0] = cl_red
```

after doing so, `print g.vs['color']` still gives

```
[(0, 0, 0.5), (0, 0, 0.5), (0, 0, 0.5)]
```

How can I assign values for individual items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just doing it backwards... do

```
g.vs[0]['color'] = cl_red
```

sorry, should be more descriptive.

`g.vs['color']` returns a list of all the node attributes. These aren't the actual attributes - it's a copy, so modifying it has no effect.

`g.vs[0]` returns the actual vertex 0. You can then modify its attributes using the dictionary interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I don't understand your full explanation. If `g.vs['color']` only returns a "copy, so modifying it has no effect", then how can I assign it to be `g.vs['color'] = 3*[cl_blue]` in the above example?

Comment: ok, i guess that's not strictly true... the explanation requires a little more. When you call `g.vs['color'] = 3*[cl_blue]`, that ends up really calling `g.vs.__setitem__('color', 3*[cl_blue])`, which the VertexSequence can translate into setting attributes for all nodes. `g.vs['color'][0]` turns into a call to `g.vs.__getitem__('color')`, which returns a list (a copy), and then the `[0]` either lets you set the first item in this copied list, or deference it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I should not have underestimated the complexity of the `=`, which magically calls `__setitem__`.